# NSUserDefaults boolForKey

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to get NSUserDefaults to work in my app.  The code below is supposed to check if there is a bool value in the NSUserDefaults called "iCloudOn".  If there is, it then assigns the value of a UISwitch to the NSUserDefault.  If there is not, it goes ahead and assigns false to the NSUserDefault.

I have marked the line that I am getting the error on.  The error I receive is "Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type."  I can't figure out why I am getting this error and what I need to do to make this work.  Can anyone help shed some light?

```
class SettingsTableViewController: UITableViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var iCloudUISwitch: UISwitch!

let appSettings = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //THIS IS THE LINE I AM GETTING AN ERROR ON
    if  let iCloudOn = appSettings.boolForKey("iCloudOn") {
        //iCloud is on
        iCloudUISwitch.on = appSettings.boolForKey("iCloudOn")
    }
    else {
        //Nothing stored in NSUserDefaults yet. Set a value.
        appSettings.setValue(false, forKey: "iCloudOn")
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function `boolForKey` does not return an optional. It always returns true or false. If the key doesn't exist in user defaults, it returns false.

You should use objectForKey, which returns `AnyObject?`, then cast it to a `Bool`.

### Edit:

If this function was being written today for Swift it would almost certainly return a `Bool?` type (Optional Bool) This would be a perfect use-case for an optional. However, NSUserDefaults was defined and written a LONG time before Swift (It was part of NextStep)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `appSettings.boolForKey('iCloudOn')` without the `if let` to get your value. According to the documentation false is returned if no value is associated to the key.

[NSUserDefaults.boolForKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/boolForKey:)